# Custom Post type is being ignored in query

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, query

I have a custom post type called "results" and on my single results page I want to perform a second query after the main loop. The second query is as follows:

```
$myquery = new WP_Query(array(
 'post_type' => 'endorsements',
   'tax_query' => array(
     array(
     'taxonomy' => 'results_categories',
     'field'    => 'slug',
     'terms' => array( 'facilitative-leaders', 'organization' )
     )
  ),
));
```

I made a second loop with the above query and what I get back are posts that are in the "results" custom post type, NOT in the 'endorsements' post type as I specified.

If I take out all the tax_query info and only ask for the 'endorsements' it works, but I need the tax info.

Far as I can see my query is correct.. been stuck on this one for a while!!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: is your post type registered with `exclude_from_search` set to true? if you set `posts_per_page` to `-1`, do you see any `endorsements` in the returned set? what happens when you add post type instead as an array: `'post_type' => array('endorsements')`?

Comment: @Milo exclude_from_search is set to false, your other recommendations still do not return posts from 'endorsements' unfortunately. Is there any other info I can provide that may help?

Comment: `var_dump($myquery)` after you run it and see what the query vars look like. I'll guess you have some code somewhere modifying the query, maybe `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: @Milo Yes, you were right, I was using pre_get_post to exclude some things, but I forgot to add && $query->is_main_query().

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I found out that I was using pre_get_post on these pages to exclude some things on the taxonomy archive pages.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_cpt' );
function exclude_cpt( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tax('results_categories') ) {
         $query->set( 'post_type', array('results') );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

BUT I forgot to make sure this was only happening in the main query, the final function is below.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_cpt' );
function exclude_cpt( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tax('results_categories') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
         $query->set( 'post_type', array('results') );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Just a note here, always do a check for admin pages as well. `pre_get_posts` also alters the back end queries, so be carefull with this. Simply just add `!is_admin()` like this `if ( !is_admin() && query->is_tax('results_categories') && $query->is_main_query() ) {`

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks for noting that very helpful to all that will read this post!

Comment: Will upvote this answer if you make that change :-)